# Importing CSV data to update existing records with Rails

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a CSV into my application witch I'd like to use to update existing and create records. My CSV data only has two headers Date and Total. I've create a import method in my model which creates everything but if I can the CSV and upload it won't update existing records, it just creates duplicates?

Here is my method, as you can see I'm finding the row by Date heading once matched using find_by, then creating a new record if this returns false and update with the data from the current row if matched but that doesn't seem to be the case, I just get duplicate rows.

```
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      entry = find_by(Date: row["Date"]) || new
      entry.update row.to_hash
      entry.save!
    end
  end
```

I hope I'm understanding this correctly. As discovered in the comments below, the CSV date format is DD-MM-YYYY and the database is storing the date as YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: have you tried using `find_by(date: row["Date"])` instead? Naming conventions in ruby state that attributes are in lower case.

Comment: @UriAgassi Thanks for the reply Uri, I've adjusted that but still getting the same result :(

Comment: Are the date field in the database and the date from the CSV formatted the same? Is the database field a date time field or a string?

Comment: @NathanFritz I've just checked and the date in my CSV is 01-02-2014 and in the database it's imported as 2014-02-01 does that make any difference? it's importing into the database but just not updating existing records, it's set as date. Thanks for replying!

Comment: I suspect that though it's converting the date to the right format for the database before it saves it, comparisons against that date and a date in a different format will fail. Try doing find_by(date:  Date.parse(row["Date"])) Does that help?

Comment: @NathanFritz Thank you very much, that works perfectly. Thanks for helping me troubleshoot. I'm going to amend my question to reflect the date formatting, if you want to answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we found in the comment thread for the question, the date was being persisted to the database in yyyy-mm-dd format.

The date being read in from the CSV file was in mm-dd-yyyy format. Doing a find_by using this format never returned results, as the format differed from that used in the database.

Date.parse will convert the string read from the CSV file into a true Date object which can be successfully compared against the date stored in the database.

So, rather than:

```
entry = find_by(Date: row["Date"]) || new
```

Use:

```
entry = find_by(Date: Date.parse(row["Date"])) || new
```